# To Get Structured Data mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i need a requirement as below can anyone please assist me depending on the parent_id and id the relation

```
 id | category_name | parent_id 

 1    Electronics         0        

 2    computer            1

 3    ram                 2

 4    Fashion             0

 5    tshirt              4

 6     round neck         5
```

i need a  requirement as below

```
category name     |      sub category     |      sub sub category  | 

Electronics                NA                        NA

Electronics                computer                  NA

Electronics                computer                  ram

Fashion                    NA                        NA

Fashion                    tshirt                    NA

Fashion                    tshirt                   round neck
```

please help

Comment: Please provide more information.. Do you want to know how to write a query to fetch values or how to create the tables?

Comment: how to write the query for this....the above is my table and below is how to display the data

Comment: Pls show us what you have tried to achive the exoected output!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: i am not getting the logic brother so that's the reason i have kept my question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of pain and suffering, I arrived at the following query.  Note that the links given as comments above did nothing for me.

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(
    SELECT COALESCE(c3.category_name, c2.category_name, c1.category_name, 'NA') AS `category name`,
        CASE WHEN c3.category_name IS NOT NULL
            THEN c2.category_name
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN c2.category_name IS NOT NULL
                    THEN c1.category_name
                    ELSE 'NA'
                END 
        END AS `sub category`,
        CASE WHEN c3.category_name IS NOT NULL
            THEN c1.category_name
            ELSE 'NA'
        END AS `sub sub category`
    FROM category c1 LEFT JOIN category c2
        ON c1.parent_id = c2.id
    LEFT JOIN category c3
        ON c2.parent_id = c3.id ) t
ORDER BY t.`category name`,
    CASE WHEN t.`sub category` = 'NA' THEN NULL ELSE t.`sub category` END,
    CASE WHEN t.`sub sub category` = 'NA' THEN NULL ELSE t.`sub sub category` END
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187f2/5)